# Units in Rect class

Tags: android, size, screen, units-of-measurement, rect

I have 854X480 android screen size.

But, when I use `drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, 570, 320), null)` this will fit the entire screen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MainLayout(this));
  }
}
class MainLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
  public MainLayout(Context context)
  {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
  }
  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, 570, 320), paint);
  }
}
```

Shouldn't it be `canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, 854, 480), paint)` that will fit entire screen?
Why does the unit I use in *Rect* class ((570, 320) in this case) differ from my screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because you are hardcoding pixels, that fit for one screen. Better way would be to scale them according to device density. Here is the method for that.

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {  
    return (int) (dp * (DEVICE_DENSITY_DPI / 160f));
}
```

Define DEVICE_DENSITY_DPI as a global object at Application level as:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

DEVICE_DENSITY_DPI = metrics.densityDpi;
```

Then, use it as follows:

```
class MainLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
  final int WIDTH = convertDpToPixel(570);
  final int HEIGHT = convertDpToPixel(320);      

  public MainLayout(Context context)
  {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), paint);
  }
}
```

Now the values will automatically change according to the device width and height, also make sure to layout MainLayout with attributes match_parent.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination